# WCF - Error getting large amount of data

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, web-config

I'm not going to talk about the error

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. 
>   To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

I've a wcf service which connects to *Microsoft Dynamics CRM*, i started the project as *.NET 4.5* however the server where it will be placed can only host *.NET 3.5*.

When i changed the WCF project framework some *Operation Contracts* stopped working when the data that it's returning is medium-large (as 1000 items inside an array).

I've checked the XML and it has ~1mb, so i don't think that it's about the *Quotas*.

The error i receive:

> Client found response content type of '', but expected 'text/xml'. The
>   request failed with an empty response.

**Server Side:**

```
public account[] GetX(DateTime? Range)
{
    Service svc = Helper.CreateService();
    account[] arr = null;

    if (Range == null)
        arr = svc.GetAllX();
    else
        arr = svc.GetAllXByDate(Range.Value);

    return arr;
}
```

Web-Config system.serviceModel:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="myBasicHttpBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
          maxArrayLength="16348" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <services>
    <service name="OROC.Proxy.ProxyService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviors">
      <endpoint name="Endpoint"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="myBasicHttpBinding"
                contract="OROC.Proxy.IProxyService" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ServiceBehaviors">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <!--<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="http" />
  </protocolMapping>-->
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Oh, and the error happens when it's returning the items, not in the *return arr;*, just after the method ends.
The fiddler catches all the XML so i guess that the problem is *client-side*

**EDIT 1 04/10/2014 10:09**

Client-Side:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>

  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="myBasicBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>

    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>

  <client>
    <endpoint name="basicEndpoint"
        address="http://localhost:58364/ProxyService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="myBasicBinding"
        contract="*"
        behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    </endpoint>
  </client>

</system.serviceModel>
```

**EDIT 2 04/10/2014 10:34**

I've tested the XML with IE and it didn't parse correctly, however when i opened the xml with visual studio it warned me about the unicode characters and it replaced them, then i saved the file and opened again with IE and it was correctly parsed. This information can be usefull.

Anyone with ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it!

I found that i needed to increase the *maxItemsInObjectGraph* but i couldn't, no matter what i would do.

How did i found it? and how did i resolve the problem?

**First problem:** i've added the reference as Web Reference and not ServiceReference and i couldn't put the ServiceBehavior and the endpoint working.

**Second problem:** I needed to enable the TraceFile so i could see more than just a simple

> The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error

**Third problem:** The serviceModel in *web.config* needed to be equal in both server and client side.

**Resolution:** First i removed the web reference and added the service reference, when i did that i needed to change some methods in code-behind (Client-side).

Then i matched the web.config's.

**Client-Side WebConfig**

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>

  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="myBasicBinding" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        <security mode="None" />
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
          maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </binding>
      <binding name="Endpoint" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>

    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>

  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:58364/ProxyService.svc" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBasicBinding"
      contract="ProxyService.IProxyService" name="basicEndpoint" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Server-Side WebConfig**

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <extensions>
    <bindingElementExtensions>
      <add name="customTextMessageEncoding" type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CustomTextMessageEncodingBindingSection, CustomTextMessageEncoder" />
    </bindingElementExtensions>
  </extensions>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="myBasicHttpBinding" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        <security mode="None" />
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
          maxArrayLength="16348" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <services>
    <service name="OROC.Proxy.ProxyService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviors">
      <endpoint name="Endpoint"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="myBasicHttpBinding"
                contract="OROC.Proxy.IProxyService" />
      <!--<endpoint kind="udpDiscoveryEndpoint" binding="ProxyService" />-->
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ServiceBehaviors">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

To discover what problem i had, i just enabled the TraceFile at the server-side webconfig and opened the file with the default program (Microsoft Service Trace Viewer).

**Diagnostics**

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true"/>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="sdt" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="TraceFile.svclog"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" on the client?

Comment: Can you modify maxArrayLength value to a ridiculously large value and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: Bacloch, no difference :(

Comment: i've found the problem, see my answer for more info.